# Detect and close "Windows Update" dialog box - vbscript .vbs file

Tags: windows, dialog

I have the vbscript code to toggle between two windows:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    WScript.Sleep 20000
    WshShell.AppActivate("Inbox - Microsoft Outlook")
    ' WshShell.SendKeys "% r"
    WScript.Sleep 20000
    WshShell.AppActivate("Firefox")
    ' WshShell.SendKeys "% r"
Loop
```

The problem is, I get "Windows Update" dialog box randomly and it shows up on screen. Is there a way to find that dialog box and close it through existing vbscript that I have? Below is the picture of dialog box:

[image]

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Richa

Comment: Any help with this pls?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that dialog can be touched by VBScript unless you were to run it with admin privileges.

I think the easiest solution it to prevent Windows from automatically installing updates. Open up Windows Update from the Control Panel, go to Change Settings, then set it to one of

- Download updates but let me choose whether to install them
- Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them

[image: Windows Update settings]

If you choose the first one, I believe you'll get a taskbar notification (balloon) when there are updates available, which won't steal focus but still let you know updates are ready.

Given that Win7 is probably only going to receive Windows Defender definition updates for the rest of its lifetime, you probably won't encounter this dialog often now.